# How many of the numbers in $A=\{1!,2!,...,2015!\}$ are square numbers?

Tags: contest-math, factorial, square-numbers

**Problem**

How many of the numbers in $A=\{1!,2!,...,2015!\}$ are square numbers?

**My thoughts**

I have no idea where to begin. I see no immediate connection between a factorial and a possible square. Much less for such ridiculously high numbers as $2015!$.

Thus, the only one I can immediately see is $1! = 1^2$, which is trivial to say the least.

Comment: A number will be square if every prime factor appears an even number of times.  If a particular prime only exists once, number cannot be a square

Comment: @Maciek - That's actually new to me. Or at least a facet I hadn't considered before. And coincidentally, every answer posted (so far) is based on this, so I needed to know it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** (for example) $13!, 14!, \dots , 25!$ are all nonsquare numbers because all of them are divisible by $13$ only once. (because $13$ is a prime)

Similarly, $17!, 18!, \dots, 33!$ are nonsquare numbers.

Go on like this.

Comment: Cool!, you only focus on primes...

Answer (score 9):

Only $1!$. For $n>1$, let $p$ be the greatest prime with $p\le n$. [Between $p$ and $2p$ there is another prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate), so $2p>n$. Therefore, $p$ occurs only once in the factorization of $n!$ and hence, $n!$ is not a square.

Answer (score 1):

Of all $n!$ only $0!$ and $1!$ are perfect squares.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171110155904/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55881.html)

> To prove that a factorial bigger than 1 can't be a perfect square,
> first think about breaking down the factorial into prime factors. For
> example, 4! = 24, and 24 = 2*2*2*3. In order for any number to be a
> perfect square, it must contain an even number of each prime factor.
>
> Now think about the largest prime less than or equal to n. Call that
> number p. That number appears only once in the list of factors
> 1*2*3*4*5*...*p*...*n, so it can't appear an odd number of times
> unless 2*p is also less than n.
>
> Now there's a semi-famous theorem called Bertrand's Postulate, which
> says that there is always a prime number between n and 2n. This is
> just  what you need to show that 2p isn't less than n - because if it
> were,  there would have to be a larger prime than p that is also less
> than n.